# after sorted one zip object , why list the object is empty

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting

I zip two list into one,then I use sorted function to order it.
But after that, I list zip object will show empty [] .

[(11, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (15, 'c'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'e'), (19, 'f'), (12, 'g'), (23, 'h'), (5, 'i'), (14, 'j'), (21, 'k'), (9, 'l'), (8, 'm'), (22, 'n'), (20, 'o'), (0, 'p'), (6, 'q'), (25, 'r'), (13, 's'), (10, 't'), (18, 'u'), (17, 'v'), (4, 'w'), (24, 'x'), (16, 'y'), (7, 'z')]

[]

```
import random
eng=[ chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('a')+26,1)]
enum_eng=zip(list(range(len(eng))),eng)
random.shuffle(eng)
enum_eng=zip(list(range(len(eng))),eng)

print(sorted(enum_eng,key=lambda x : x[1]))
print(list(enum_eng))
```

I want to compare sorted zip list before and after.

Comment: Because zip creates an iterator, you can't consume it twice

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sounds like an answer to me, or at least a duplicate question.